# Spark Unit tests: Start spark session with HiveMetaStore running on an in-memory database

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hive-metastore

We have written some Spark pipelines which uses DataFrames as well as some Hive SQLs (CREATE TABLE xxxx). Inside our unit tests, we need to start sparkSession with Hive support in local mode as follows:

```
SparkSession.builder()
         .master("local[*]")
         .config("spark.sql.catalogImplementation","hive")
         .enableHiveSupport()
         .getOrCreate()
```

I assume this spawn off a HiveMetaStore running locally on some port.I couldn't find much information on what happens internally in local mode.
My questions are:

1. Is my assumption correct about spawning a HiveMetaStore process?
2. What kind of database does it use to store Hive metadata? Apache Derby?
3. For the unit tests, is it possible to configure this to use some in-memory database like H2?

Comment: Will that help? https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/AdminManual+Metastore+3.0+Administration. Derby does run in in-memory mode by default, btw.

Comment: I would also recommend to seriously consider using something like https://github.com/holdenk/spark-testing-base for unit-testing your Spark

Comment: ive been trying to use this.. but this still doesnt support Spark 3.0 with Hive support.I tried to build the branch with Spark 3.0 but it fails for Hive SQLs.

Comment: https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-sql-hive-metastore.html

Comment: Follow it may be it will help. it has local setup in depth. https://dzone.com/articles/detailed-guide-setup-apache-spark-development-envi